# How to load a pre-populated Sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I am trying to use pre-populated Sqlite database in android and it working fine with 100 to 1000 data but when i am loading the 100000 data row it got stuck i mean it took lot of time to load i find that other dictionary app which has same number of data doesn't hang so can any one help me on this..

I am using the below code for copy the data and i call  it from the main and the code is also in main.

```
 private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
        String outFileName = DatabaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseHelper.DBNAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[4096];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w("MainActivity","DB copied");
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I use the following code for the calling the copy function

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
public Adapter dap;
ArrayList<String> myObject1;
int check=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

  File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
   // if(false == database.exists())
        if(check==0){
        mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Copy db
        if(copyDatabase(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            check=1;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Can any one help me out how to do it correctly....

Comment: See if this helps. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: @ cricket_007  thanks i will check this out but can you  tell me whats wrong with my code it would be a great help

Comment: Not sure. I haven't used very large sqlite databases before

Comment: @ cricket_007 should i use the background running or is there any way to copy data faster

Comment: What is the size in MBs of your DB?

Comment: @ Eric B 15MB of text data with dictionary format

Comment: How long does your app take to copy it?

Comment: @ Eric B more than 15 min so what can i  do now

Comment: I think increasing your buffer size will give you better performance. Try changing it to `16384`. Like this `byte[]buff = new byte[16384];`

Comment: @ Eric B. Ok let me try your suggestion

Comment: no its not improving the speed and any other suggestion...

Comment: keep your copyDB()  functionality in AsyncTask doInBackground() method

Comment: @ Surya Bondada can you give me some suggestion how to do it with above code....

Comment: Just write an AsyncTask and call the copy database method. It's fairly straightforward if you ever wrote one. Also, how do you know other dictionary apps use a SQLite database?

Comment: Update---> NOW ITS WORKING and thanks for the suggestion though my previous code was fine  and the problem was with  the small coding error and the correct buffer size